# How to get directory git branch diff using kdiff

Tags: git, diff, difftool, kdiff3

I have configured **kDiff3** with my **git**.

What I need is to see directory difference between two branches. when I run

`git difftool <headbranch>`

command it opens all files one by one. But that is not I want.

Answer (score 20):

**git-difftool(1)** now satisfies this use case. Just use the --dir-diff (or -d) switch:

```
-d
--dir-diff
  Copy the modified files to a temporary location and perform
  a directory diff on them. This mode never prompts before
  launching the diff tool.
```

So for example:

```
git difftool -d --tool=kdiff3 10c25f0da62929cca0b559095a313679e4c9800e..980de1bbe1f42c327ed3c9d70ac2ff0f3c2ed4e1
```

See also https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html

Comment: I use this command as well, but also add the parameter `--no-symlink` so that any changes I make in kdiff3 will apply the current checked out working directory.

Comment: The `--no-symlink` option will also quiet KDiff3's "Error: Conflicting File Types"

Answer (score 2):

Let's say, we have the two branches ***master*** and ***base***
In order to see the difference between these branches, just execute:

```
git difftool -d base:src/ master:src/
```

Then your preset diff tool should get started, in my case kdiff3.
Or you can also use the `--tool` option to start another one:
e.g. with **vimdiff**

```
git difftool -d --tool=vimdiff  base:src/ master:src/
```

or with **kdiff3** the same way

```
git difftool -d --tool=kdiff3  base:src/ master:src/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
git diff --name-status <other-branch>
```

It lists files with differences, with a status of A/M/D.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Also kDiff3 is good to compare directories. A/M/D is really a great help.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found possibilities to see directory difference between two branches in a directory comparison mode using kdiff3 and standard git tools.

What could be done using standard tools (fix me if I am wrong:) is file by file comparison using difftool, and overview in console using:

```
git diff --name-status <other-branch>
```

But I have found [Comprehensive Graphical Git Diff Viewer Script](https://nitingupta.dev/post/comprehensive-graphical-git-diff-viewer/), that did the work for me as desired - to compare the whole directory in kdiff3.

The tool is just a shell script that creates branches-to-be-compared snapshots in /tmp folder and runs kdiff3 folder comparison on them.

Checkout the script [here](https://gist.github.com/nitingupta910/11e4a202b2dc25cf280b6f584d6e4e38#file-git-diffc)